# How can I debug Invoke-Command running a script on remote computer with Visual Studio Code?

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code, debugging, vscode-debugger

I have some PowerShell running in the general form:

```
LocalCode # L1
$result = Invoke-Command -Session $remoteComputer -ScriptBlock { # L2
    RemoteCode # L3
} # L4
LocalCode $result # L5
```

Where $remoteComputer is a valid session to a remote computer.

Using Visual Studio Code, if I set a breakpoint on line 1 or line 5, the breakpoint hits just fine. Setting a breakpoint in line 3 never hits, and stepping into line 2 actually steps over the script block entirely.

[`Set-PSBreakpoint`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/set-psbreakpoint) specifically mentions that it doesn't work on remote computers, but I would rather stay in Visual Studio Code on my local machine anyways, and not modify the code either.